# How might I go about using the API to search for a user by email, but ensuring that it is an exact match?

Tags: search, rest-api

I am using the API currently to search for a user by email and then getting the ID if the user and then executing a change to the account based on the ID. The only issue is, it seems that when I search, the search doesn't require it to be exact. I am wanting it to be exact.

Example is, I search for a user using:

```
"GET /wp-json/wp/v2/users?search=username@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200
```

It comes back with the correct user, but if I also tried:

```
"GET /wp-json/wp/v2/users?search=username@gmai HTTP/1.1" 200
```

That also came back with the user. I am developing just using a test site so I only have a few users, but I foresee that this could be a problem. I am needing to search for one specific user by email at a time and I was hoping that when I got a result back I could validate it by checking if the email address shown in the json search result matched the email that was passed to it, but it doesn't look like it displays the email address in the results either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to get things a bit closer to what I am after?

Comment: I'd suggest looping over the results and comparing the searched-for email address and the result's email address and check for an exact match.

Comment: That would be no problem, the only thing is, when I search I am not seeing the email address show up in the results. Is there something else I have to pass along with it to show the email as well?

Comment: Oh, you're right, the email address isn't included in the response. At least for an unauthenticated request.

Comment: I am making an authenticated request using Oauth2, I am still not seeing an email address though?

Comment: By that all I meant is that I only tried an unauthenticated request tried to double check what you were saying. It could also be true for authenticated requests.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this by installing a plugin called "PHP Snippits" that lets you add code as if you were adding it to functions.php, but through the admin panel. Then I did some reasearch on how to add a custom endpoint and then how to query a user and came up with this. It seems to be working well, and is better than what I had originally hoped for. I just pass the endpoint the email and I get back the specific userID I needed.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'endpoint/v1', 'email/(?P<stringvar>[^/]+)', array(
        'methods'             => 'GET',
        'callback'            => 'user_email',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can('edit_others_posts');
        },
    ) );
});

function user_email($data) {

    // Get user by their email address
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $data['stringvar']);
    $userId = $user->ID;
    $user_data = [$userId, $data['stringvar']];


    wp_reset_postdata();

    return rest_ensure_response($user_data);
}
```